# A handy script to execute a program for all files in a directory one by one

Tags: bash

I have 61 .fastq files, I want to run an app for each one of them separately, resulting in 61 output files, so how to write a script avoiding to list all 61 files? I tried a couple of simple scripts as I am not a pro, but when running, the program fails to open fastq files, however, when I run the program for only one file, there is no problem in opening it.
do you think, technically speaking, the script below is correct and should work? or am I missing something?

```
samples="$(ls data)"
echo ${samples} | tr " " "\n" | while read sample; do
    gsnap -D ./cinxia  ./data/${sample}.fastq ; done
```

OR

```
for sample in /data/*.fastq; do
    gsnap -D ./cinxia  ./data/${sample}.fastq ; done
```

I expect the program gsnap runs for each one of my 61 fastq file and gives me a result each time with the same file name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Both scripts will probably work, so it's unclear what the problem is. Please post the error message. See [ask] and [mre] for reference.

Comment: is that a typo? `${sample}.fastq`

Comment: I think I got you! I shouldn't mention ${sample}.fastq, I should only mention ${sample} because I noticed it is adding an extra .fastq! right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: You'll probably find it easiest to use Make for tasks like this.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is better, it's bad form to sniff the output of `ls`. I think if you have certain characters in the file names you could get in trouble, but as long as you know the input file names are "normal" you can get away with just using quotes, like so:

```
for sample in /data/*.fastq; do
    gsnap -D ./cinxia "./data/${sample}.fastq"
done
```

The quotes will make it so, for example, if your file name has spaces it runs:

```
gsnap -D ./cinxia "./data/file name with spaces.fastq"
```

You can see that without the quotes, the command line would see that is many words and not one file. Be careful when dealing with quoting and expansion in bash, it's confusing! In some situations, you get bad results even when using quotes.

What would happen if you had a file named `badfile; rm -rf /`?

Comment: Your last one is only an issue if you try to `eval` a string built using its value. Ordinary word-splitting and pathname expansion won't try to delete anything.

Comment: *"Even with quotes, sometimes you get bad results with funky file names"*. That's only true for filenames that could be interpreted as options, like `-rf foobar`. In that case just put a double dash before the filenames (`rm -- "$sample"`) or use a dot slash like in this case.

Comment: @wjandrea and chepner thanks for the clarification. Without a shell and a manual handy, I usually can't remember in what order the various splitting and expansions take place so I tend to be overly cautious. I'll edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

While izzy's answer is correct and straightforward, if you're looking for a performance boost (pending correctness checks and benchmarking), you may wish to consider the following approach:

```
find data -name *.fastq -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 2>/dev/null \
  | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -P"$(nproc)" gsnap -D ./cinxia "{}"
```

`xargs -P<num>` can help parallelize `gsnap` invocation to `<num>` levels, where `nproc` tells it the number of processing units available to the current process (which may be less than the number of online processors).